# Method inside output buffer not working

Tags: php, oop, require, output-buffering

Assume having just a trivial snippet:

```
public function myMethod($file)
{
    require $file;
}

public function capture($file, array $args)
{
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    ob_start();

    $this->myMethod($file); //not working
    require $file; //works

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Could anyone explain why the snippet above works in case of using `require` only and not when using the method?

Comment: i think you have to `return` your `require`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make available the parameters to `myMethod`:

```
public function myMethod($file, array $args)
{
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    require $file;
}

public function capture($file, array $args)
{
    ob_start();

    $this->myMethod($file, $args);

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

See about [the scope of a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can not include (require) a file in function since it can be call many times , so require will be called again n again .. So have a try

```
 public function myMethod($file)
    {
        require_once $file;
    }
```